# C/C++ Programs Keeps Crashing During Compile And Run

Tags: c, windows

I'm a very very beginner to C programming language
I wonder that there's a problem with my IDE or I can't figure what.
The problem is when a write some codes and compile them it runs great but suddenly stops working. This is for every program and every IDE and even tested this on two of my computers but both did the same problem.

For example the most simplest code crashes, like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){

    int num1, num2, result;
    result = num1 + num2;

    printf("Enter Value 1:\n");
    scanf("%d",num1);
    printf("\nEnter Value 2:");
    scanf("%d",num2);

    printf("The result of %d + %d is %d",num1,num2,result);


    getch();
    return 0;


}
```

And when I run it on CodeBlocks or DevCPP or compile it with MinGW or VC++ compiler it crashes after entering the data at scanf to the program. And by the way my compiler and IDE is installed and configured correctly and with no problems. But IDK all of my compiled programs keeps crashing! Even a simple HELLO WORLD prorgam! Please help me.
My first PC:
INTEL Pentium D 3.4 GhZ 
4GB RAM DDR3
Windows 8.1 Pro x64

My second PC:
Intel Atom 1.4 GhZ
2GB RAM 
Windows 8.1 Pro x86

And I turned off my AV to make sure it's not the problem from AV but same problem again. Crash.

[CodeBlocks IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivbe8.png)

[DevCPP IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj5RY.png)

Error information:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: Arithmetic Operations.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    57a9fa0c
  Fault Module Name:    msvcrt.dll
  Fault Module Version: 7.0.9600.16384
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5215f944
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000001dd5c
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1065
  Additional Information 1: 3d05
  Additional Information 2: 3d052cae4082fb501044f19c5df730a9
  Additional Information 3: 4191
  Additional Information 4: 41915c3946c3709cfe888641ded802fc

Please help me!

Comment: Arguments for `scanf()` must be a pointers: `scanf("%d",&num1); scanf("%d",&num2);`

Comment: `result = num1 + num2;` move to after input `num1` and `num2`.

Comment: `result = num1 + num2;` is undefined behavior as you never initialized the variables.

Comment: Technically `C / C++` is *undefined* as the expression is unsequenced.

Comment: Not only `result = num1 + num2` is undefined behavior here, it's also broken logic: you're first computing the sum and then actually getting the information about the numbers to sum. You first drink water and only then pour it into your glass.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to pass *pointers* to the integers in `scanf`:

`scanf("%d", &num1);`

2. You need to skip over the implicit newline character when receiving the second quantity. A simple hack is to put a space in the second `scanf` string:

`scanf(" %d", &num2);`

3. Your program behaviour is *undefined* as you are reading uninitialised values of `num1` and `num2` when computing, too early, `result`. Move `result = num1 + num2;` to after `num1` and `num2` have been computed.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I'm dumb, I was looking at the argument for the format string, you should however pass the integers into scanf as pointers.

Additionally, you're setting result to num1 + num2 before you even set those values.

Comment: His format strings are *indeed* const char*

Answer (score 1):

In c language scanf method use with `&` sign

```
printf("Enter Value 1:\n");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("\nEnter Value 2:");
scanf("%d",&num2);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13280595)